# Link that takes to a specific view controller from html source (example: instagram links)

Tags: html, ios, hyperlink

I am looking for a way to create a link in a HTML blog that takes the user to my iOS application, and specifically to a view controller that will show the requested info. How would I would I go about generating the link and have the app recognise which link the user pressed on to take to the view controller.

The example that comes to mind, is when you find an instagram link in a website that takes the user to the instagram app then to the picture associated with the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a custom url scheme within the plist of your app. Once installed, every app (and of course Safari can) open your app by requesting such an url.
If you embed this in your blog, your app will be launched and the parameter given via didFinishLaunvhingWithOptions:

Well documented at Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1

Edit: if you want to see an example what these schemes look like and how they are used, Instagram defined their url scheme here http://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/